# PSD Design Layout in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I need your help please I am so stuck with this.

I have the following PSD login screen called "city guide":

[City Guide PSD](https://symu.co/freebies/mobile-apps/cityguide-mobile-app-psd/)

I am able to implement the blue background and the white images around it using the layered layout successfully in CN1.

I am however getting stuck when trying to come up with the right layout for the word "cityGuide" in the centre and the text beneath it and then the two buttons at the bottom.

I tried border layout and I got the city guide in the middle and the buttons at the bottom.

But the text "Explore the best places..." is either positioned right below the phrase "CityGuide" or right above the bottom buttons. I am not able to position it half way between the "CityGuide" and the bottom buttons.

Any help will be much, much appreciated.

Regards,
Salah.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an absolute center border layout where the cityguide logo and the text beneath are at the center within a `BoxLayout.Y_AXIS` and a sensible amount of padding between them.

The bottom buttons would be in another `BoxLayout.Y_AXIS` at the `SOUTH` portion of the border layout.

Comment: Dear Shai, Thanks a lot for your help. I could now roughly get something similar to the PSD design even though not in the exact position as shown in the design. For example the logo label is coming below the heart shape but in the design it is shown to be between the heart and the locker shapes. I also tried to position the text of the buttons on the centre of the buttons but I think codename one only support top, bottom, left or right when the button has an icon.

Comment: If that's important to you then you can take a very different approach. Create 3 blue backgrounds with shapes and divide the screen based on a table layout. Place the first blue background as the background to the city guide logo and give it 45% of the height. Then add the heart shape segment and give it 10% of the height then add the rest in the last 45%. Personally I wouldn't bother though... This can work great for portrait but then when you rotate the device it won't look as great and the amount of effort probably isn't worth it.